# Time taken for customs check in Brisbane Australia

Tags: customs-and-immigration, australia

What is the average time taken to clear a customs checkpoint in Brisbane ? 
I am (not an Australian citizen) flying in from the US in a flight that lands at 6.15 AM and have a connecting flight to Darwin at 8.30 AM. Would this be a sufficient time window ?

Comment: Always tell the attendants that you have a connecting flight, they will usually help you move faster through the line.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sounds like you're on QF8 connecting to QF824 which means it's all on the one carrier - so worst case if there's a problem and you miss your flight Qantas will simply put you on a later flight to Darwin.

The standard "Minimum Connection Time" at Brisbane between those 2 flights is 2 hours, so you're within that window which means that a connection is at least possible.

Unfortunately Brisbane, like most Australian airports, has different Domestic and International terminals, located a few kilometers apart.  Thankfully there is a landside bus which is free for connecting Qantas passengers which runs every 10-20 minutes so the connection is not difficult, but can take 30 minutes to get between terminals if you're unlucky.

QF8 is one of the first flights to arrive in the morning, and frequently arrives early, which means that there's normally not a large backup at immigration (especially as most of the passengers on QF8 continue on to Sydney without going through immigration).

So presuming your flight is relatively on-time (or early!) you should have no problems making your connection.

Comment: There's queues for both Immigration, then after baggage collection another for customs. The latter depends on the queue size, and how much screening they decide you need

Comment: Would you also be able to tell if I will go through customs/immigration in Brisbane or Darwin or both ?

Comment: Brisbane only. Generally in Australia you go through immigration at your first point of entry, however there are a few exceptions, including QF8 if you carry on to SYD as the BNE-SYD leg is considered an international flight. However as you're getting off in BNE and moving to a domestic flight, you clear immigration/customs in Brisbane.

Comment: If the two flights are on the same booking, if you miss the Darwin flight due to customs/immigration/connection issues, the airline will generally get you on to the next flight. If they are on *different* bookings, then missing the Darwin flight may be considered a no-show and you may lose that airfare.

Comment: @Sam Actually Qantas will (as a matter of policy) re-accommodate regardless of whether they are on the same booking or not. However what you have said is indeed true of many other airlines.

Comment: @Doc - In July 2008 I missed a flight from Sydney to Brisbane when I turned up ~= 1 day late in Sydney from Beijing due to a major problem with another airline. The final QANTAS leg had been booked separately. On asking for a new ticket QANTAS advised that I had lost my money as I'd been a no-show on a standalone flight. After smiling sweetly at them and telling them ~ that I knew they didn't have to but they were such marvellous people that I'd knew they see me right (yes, I said all that :-) ) they provided a "free" ticket. ...

Comment: ... BUT they gave every indication until I persisted that they were not going to. They MAY have changed their policy since then to provides a replacement as a matter of course - hopefully so.

Comment: @RussellMcMahon I was referring to when the first flight is another Qantas flight, as it is here. BTW, it's "Qantas", not "QANTAS".

Comment: @Doc - Qantas / QANTAS. Yes, you are indeed correct in fact if not in long irrelevant anciem regime memory :-). Fact wins, of course. The name was QANTAS long ago (circa 1920's) when it was an acronym*, but was changed to Qantas as a name somewhere along the line, as you no doubt know. It's still QANTAS on their logo, but that of course counteth not. | * "Queensland and Northern Territory Aerial Services". Should have been QaNTAS, no? :-).

Comment: @Doc - I just looked at the country list on your profile. About the same number of countries as me, but you have visited 18 that I haven't. Interesting that such a degree of overlap disparity occurs. Current plans are to add India shortly, and maybe a few more depending on circumstances, time and money.

Comment: @Doc would you also know if the trolleys in Brisbane Airport are free/charged ? If charged, then will it be wise to get a few dollar coins in currency exchange ? I think AU has only coins for 1 dollar.